# using acf() for multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `acf()` function to calculate the autocorrelation of
each column in a matrix. I managed to generate a multiple plot when I was experimenting, but the titles suggested the acf was calculated between adjacent columns in the matrix, which is something I don't want. I want only the acf plot for individual columns.

```
lapply(split(A,col(A)), function(ts) acf(ts, lag.max=10))
```

where `A` is a matrix with 500 columns and 100 rows. I just need 500 acf plots or acf values for each corresponding column.
Can anyone suggest me any improvement?

Comment: `apply(A, 2, acf)` or `apply(A, 2, function(ts) acf(ts, ...))` should do it

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it's even simple. Except for 500 plots. Maybe `apply(A, 2, function(ts) acf(ts, lag.max=10))`, it would avoid `split`.

Comment: Dear Sotos, thanks for the reply. I just get the acf values with apply(A, 2, acf). I also need the acf plots.

Comment: dear rui, is there any ways to get the plot?